# How to tell dotnet watch to run a different build configuration?

Tags: docker-compose, dotnet-watch

Today I have a container running `dotnet watch -v --project ".\\MyProject" run --no-launch-profile` and the "MyProject" folder is mapped transparently to a .NET Core project of my solution. So whenever I alter a file in my Visual Studio it's picked up immediately inside the container and recompiled to allow quick alteration and testing. However I've noticed that this causes conflict issues when I build on my host machine causing a conflict over the `bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\MyProject.exe`

To solve this situation I wanted to see if I can pass an argument/parameter/configuration/... anything to `dotnet watch` that would tell it to use a different build configuration (copy of Debug really but called Container so that it'd create a separate folder and not conflict with the host Visual Studio)

Sadly I have not been able to locate an example or documentation on how to do this with `dotnet watch`. Is this possible? Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than target a different build configuration with `dotnet watch`, you can solve this by changing the output directory based on a built-in dotnet environment variable, `DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER`.

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(UsingMicrosoftNETSdk)' == 'true'">
    <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)/obj/**/*</DefaultItemExcludes>
    <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)/bin/**/*</DefaultItemExcludes>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(UsingMicrosoftNETSdk)' == 'true' AND '$(DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER)' == 'true'">
    <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)/obj/container/</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
    <BaseOutputPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)/bin/container/</BaseOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(UsingMicrosoftNETSdk)' == 'true' AND '$(DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER)' != 'true'">
    <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)/obj/local/</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
    <BaseOutputPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)/bin/local/</BaseOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```